# Why is sum of square root (given product) maximized with equal summands?

Tags: inequality, summation

Prove $\sum_{t=1}^{T}\sqrt{x_t-1}$, where $x_t\ge 1$ and $\prod_{t=1}^{T}x_t\le T$, gets its maximum when $x_t=T^{1/T}$.

Preliminary idea:
The square root is a concave function. Sum of concave functions is concave.

Comment: Can you use majorization inequality? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality

Comment: Do you know Lagrange multipliers? It seems to me that you can impose $\prod x_i=T$ in this situation, then the Lagrange condition reads $(x_i-1)^{-1/2}=\lambda \prod_{j \neq i} x_j$, now multiply by $x_i$ to find that $\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_i-1}}=\lambda T$ (independent of $i$). So now each $x_i$ can only be one of two values (one greater than 2 the other less than 2).

Comment: I guess all indices $i$ should read $t$ ?

Comment: There might be a geometric view to this inequality by considering $x_t$ as $\sec^2(\theta_t)$ so that the target sum can be the area of a "fan" while the constraint can be a iteratively projected length. but I haven't figure out some key aspects yet.